# MySQL Insert Into Issues

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to PHP/MYSQL so im sry if you feel this is a bad question but i cant get this to work. Its for a login form. The issue i have is with the insert into with the insert query part. I apreciate if anyone could help me get this fixed
:) TY in advance.

```
    function InsertIntoDB(&$formvars)
{

    $confirmcode = $this->MakeConfirmationMd5($formvars['email']);

    $formvars['confirmcode'] = $confirmcode;

    $insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(
            name,
            email,
            username,
            password,
            confirmcode
            )
            values
            (
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['name']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['email']) . '",
            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['username']) . '",
            "' . md5($formvars['password']) . '",
            "' . $confirmcode . '"
            )';      
    if(!mysqli_query( $this->connection, $insert_query ))
    {
        $this->HandleDBError("Error inserting data to the table\nquery:$insert_query");
        return false;
    }        
    return true;
}
```

Comment: echo $insert_query and provide us its result.

Comment: after return true or?

Comment: learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: before if and after $insert_query. Write `echo $insert_query;` and give that output.

Comment: insert into fgusers3( name, email, username, password, confirmcode ) values ( "Test Name", "mail@hotmail.com", "testuser", "a1da19bed8699f25bb6849c05976a5da", "d9033c0d9844556dc4b3cd1414c80079" )

Comment: @jeppe004 show your full code show that we can debug it. now we can't use these functions properly

Comment: run this query direct to phpmyadmin and check for sql error.

Comment: @mamta 800 lines bit too muxh but i can post a pastebin. http://pastebin.com/euZLb7Hv

Comment: as im still rly new to this. what part? sry for stupid questions

Comment: on another note: MD5 is a weak hash function adn should NOT be used!

Comment: run your above query directly in your mysql database and check for sql error.

Comment: run this insert into fgusers3( name, email, username, password, confirmcode ) values ( "Test Name", "mail@hotmail.com", "testuser", "a1da19bed8699f25bb6849c05976a5da", "d9033c0d9844556dc4b3cd1414c80079" ) direct to phpmyadmin and check for sql error

Comment: oh wow it was a part with phone number which accidentally was there... i feel so stupid ty all. i learned how to debug atleast :D

Comment: @JRsz what do you recommend instead?

Comment: For a very secure one use SHA512 with a salt. http://php.net/manual/de/function.hash.php